# File System API states it can't open the documents folder because it contains system files, which it doesn't

Tags: javascript, native-file-system-api-js

I am struggling to understand if this is a bug or a feature of the new File System API. When using showDirectoryPicker and selecting the standard Windows documents directory, or the downloads directory, a pop-up appears stating that it can't open the folder because it contains system files, which it does not. Has anyone found a way around this, or am I missing something obvious?

[image]

Here is a fully functional example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File System API</title>
</head>
<button onclick="checkDirExists();">Initialize</button>
<body>

</body>
<script>

async function checkDirExists(){
    const homeDirHdl = await window.showDirectoryPicker({
        startIn: 'documents',
    });
    if (homeDirHdl){
        const draftsDirHdl = await homeDirHdl.getDirectoryHandle('drafts', {create: true});
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the "*[mcve]*" code you're using to try to access the directory?

Comment: Working code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design the File System Access API excludes certain folders from being opened or limits access to them. They are listed as the so-called [well-known directories](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#enumdef-wellknowndirectory) in the spec. Concretely, they are:

- **`desktop`**: The user’s Desktop directory, if such a thing exists. For example this could be `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop`, `/Users/username/Desktop`, or `/home/username/Desktop`.
- **`documents`**: Directory in which documents created by the user would typically be stored. For example `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents`, `/Users/username/Documents`, or `/home/username/Documents`.
- **`downloads`**: Directory where downloaded files would typically be stored. For example `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Downloads`, `/Users/username/Downloads`, or `/home/username/Downloads`.
- **`music`**: Directory where audio files would typically be stored. For example `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music`, `/Users/username/Music`, or `/home/username/Music`.

- **`pictures`**: Directory where photos and other still images would typically be stored. For example `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Pictures`, `/Users/username/Pictures`, or `/home/username/Pictures`.
- **`videos`**: Directory where videos/movies would typically be stored. For example `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Videos`, `/Users/username/Movies`, or `/home/username/Videos`.

Typically, browsers also block access to *system* directories like `C:\Windows`.

The reason these folders are blocked are *(i)*, preventing access to system-critical files (a web application should not be able to wipe your `Windows` folder) and *(ii)* preventing files to be abused as identifiers (*e.g.*, two independent apps which had access to the user's downloads folder could create and then check for the existence of an identifying file). See the relevant section of the [spec](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#privacy-wide-access) for more details and background.

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/72027437/14188773 said, you can't do that with the FSA API functions, but you can do it using the `drop/paste` events. For example you can copy/paste your drive folders:

```js
  window.addEventListener('paste', handleInput)

  let driveHandles = {}
  async function handleInput ({ dataTransfer }) {
    const drives = [...dataTransfer.files].map(file => file.name.endsWith('_drive') && file.name[0])
    const handles = await Promise.all([...dataTransfer.items].map(item => item.getAsFileSystemHandle()))
    currentHandle = handles[0]
    for (let i = 0; i < drives.length; ++i) {
      const drive = drives[i]
      if (drive) {
        driveHandles[drive] = handles[i]
      }
    }
  }
```

which creates a map of drive handles, which are root folders you can't normally access using the FSA API, then you can save them via IDB and persist them across sessions. this lets u access stuff like system volume information etc